# Yii2 Пагинация и ListPager

Tags: ajax, yii2, pjax

Так сразу к делу попытался сделать ajax пагинацию на yii2 и в итоге... кароче она не работает, прошу помогите; Вот код view:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($adverts as $advert): ?>
            <div class="obyavlenie">
                <div class="col-lg-3 kartinka">
                    <a href="<?=Url::to(['category/view', 'id' => $advert['id']]);?>">
                        <?=Html::img('@web/images/'.$advert['images'], ['alt' => $advert['name']]);?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9">
                    <p class="obyav_name">
                        <a href="<?=Url::to(['category/view', 'id' => $advert['id']]);?>">
                            <?php echo $advert['name'];?>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="obyav-info">
                        <?php if (strlen($advert['description']) > 150) {
                            $desc = substr($advert['description'], 0, 100);
                            $desc .= "...";
                            echo $desc;
                        } else {
                            echo $advert['description'];
                        } ;?>
                    </p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li class="list-city"><?php echo $advert['city'];?></li>
                        <li class="list-name"><?php echo $advert['user_name'];?></li>
                        <li class="list-email"><a href="email:<?php echo $advert['email'];?>"><?php echo $advert['email'];?></a></li>
                        <li class="list-tel"><a href="tel:<?php echo $advert['tel'];?>"><?php echo $advert['tel'];?></a></li>
                        <li class="list-sum"><?php echo number_format($advert['price'], 2, '.', ' ');?> руб.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo LinkPager::widget([
            'pagination' => $pages,
        ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Вот код controller:

```
 $adverts_all = Advert::find()->select('advert.*, user.name as user_name, user.tel, user.email')->where(['advert.type' => 'active', 'user.type' => 'active'])->leftJoin('user', 'user.id = advert.user_id')->orderBy(['advert.id' => SORT_DESC])->asArray();
    // подключаем класс Pagination, выводим по 8 пунктов на страницу
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $adverts_all->count(), 'pageSize' => 8]);
    // приводим параметры в ссылке к ЧПУ
    $pages->pageSizeParam = false;
    $adverts = $adverts_all->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();

    return $this->render('index', compact('categorys', 'adverts', 'pages'));
```

Кстати нашел один подвох данный код не работает только на главной странице, на остальных он работает.

Comment: Все почти разобрался, вся проблема в ЧПУ однако ссылка на первую страницу формируется неправильно((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так теперь я точно разобрался, вся проблема действительно оказалась в ЧПУ ну и мой пример кода вдруг нужен будет:

```
'rules' => [
            'category/<name:([a-zA-Z-_]+)>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/view',
            'category/<name:([a-zA-Z-_]+)>' => 'category/view',
            '/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/index',
            '' => 'category/index',
        ],
```